# how to get a Matlab timestamp in floating point (data type double) seconds

Tags: matlab

I need a function that returns a timestamp, in seconds, as a Matlab double (floating point) value.
ie.
I want a function present_seconds() to return the present time, in seconds, as a Matlab double value.

Timestamp can be elapsed CPU seconds, or seconds of epoch.  (I'm using it as a relative value.)

Comment: *Note: I didn't downvote*.  The question is ambiguous and ill-posed. "floating point timestamp" is ambiguous - it could mean anything. For one thing, every time stamp that is calculated is with respect to a reference point. For example, Java calculates this since January 1, 1970 with `System.currentTimeMillis()` for it in milliseconds. With that, you have not specified what the reference point is.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, `tic` and `toc` may be what you need.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
function p = present_seconds
    p = 3600 * 24 * now;
end
```

Comment: Continuing from the above comment, you would also need to shed light on what `now` means.  `now` represents the amount of days that have elapsed since January 1, 0 AD.  The significand represents the number of days while the mantissa represents the fraction of the day on the current day that has passed since midnight.  For example, `6 p.m. --> 0.75`. Multiplying by `24 x 3600` is correct to calculate the number of seconds per day so this does do what its advertised, but the question and answer don't really match with each other. You should amend to this answer to specify what `now` implies.